# Rails delegate - How it works

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I am confused on rails delegate functionality. Though i refer to [apidoc](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) 
I need a better understanding. Here are 2 types of delegates i found on open source projects.

```
delegate :id, :guid, to: :person, prefix: true

delegate :last_name, :image_url, :tag_string, :bio, to: :profile
```

What is difference between them? How much does it affect with and without the using of `prefix`? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`prefix: true` specifies that you must include the model name as a prefix to the delegate method.  So for a Widget instance you would call it like so:

```
widget.person_id
widget.person_guid
```

Not specifying `prefix` means you call the delegate without the model name prefix, e.g.

```
widget.last_name
widget.image_url
```

etc.